# InternetExplorer SendKeys executing in VBA

Tags: vba, sendkeys

I have to press some keys on an IE page. Sometimes it works fine and sometimes no.

When I run the code step by step with F8 they always get pressed in the VBA window.
When I run the tool with F5 they sometimes get pressed in IE, where I need them, and sometimes in VBA. What can I do to prevent this?

Here is part of the code:

```
Set Elements = IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("REQ")(0)
Elements.Value = 10001
Set objWSS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Elements.Focus
objWSS.SendKeys "^{TAB}"
objWSS.SendKeys ("{DOWN}")
objWSS.SendKeys ("{TAB}{RIGHT}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding DoEvents to allow Windows Messages to be fully handled:

```
Set Elements = IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("REQ")(0)
Elements.Value = 10001
Set objWSS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Elements.Focus
objWSS.SendKeys "^{TAB}"
DoEvents
objWSS.SendKeys ("{DOWN}")
DoEvents
objWSS.SendKeys ("{TAB}{RIGHT}")
DoEvents
```

Comment: The results are the same :(